# How to adjust display resolution in Android Studio 1.2

Tags: android-studio, screen-resolution

How can I change display resolution of Android Studio IDE? Background: I was running Android Studio 1.1 on 1920 x 1080 Win 8.1 with 14 inch screen. Although the font was not very clear the size was acceptable. Android Studio has just updated to version 1.2 and the whole IDE resolution has changed. I have tried changing the compatibility setting with no improvement. I can change the editor font and console text to make it readable but the toolbar buttons are too small for comfort.

Update: OK, I've learned to live with it, but I'm surprised no-one else has the problem.

Comment: I have this problem too, updated yesterday and everything was small  :(